# java.io dilemma

Tags: java, filereader, inputstreamreader

The classes java.io.Reader and java.io.InputStreamReader both have read methods with the exact same signature

```
public int read(char[] charbuf, int offset, int length) throws IOException
```

Now according to the java documentation the class java.io.FileReader inherits **both** these read() methods from **both** the above-mentioned classes.

Now as FileReader extends InputStreamReader which further extends Reader

```
(Reader <-- Inputstreamreader <-- FileReader)
```

and the read() has same signature in both classes, shouldn't it have been that InputStreamReader overrode the read() from Reader and FileReader inherited that over-ridden method?? Or am i missing something here??

Also the two read()s inherited by FileReader have slightly different functionality (something about one blocks while waiting for input while the other doesn't).

Comment: The docs don't say "it inherits both", it just lists the methods that are inherited from superclasses, by superclass. It doesn't go in and remove inherited methods from classes "higher up" in the inheritance chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method in `InputStreamReader` provides the implementation for the *abstract* method in `Reader`. `FileReader` doesn't override that method any further; it just inherits the implementation from `InputStreamReader`.

Note that there are *four* signatures for read:

```
public int read()
public int read(char[] cbuf, int offset, int length)
public int read(char[] cbuf)
public int read(CharBuffer target)
```

`InputStreamReader` only overrides the first two of these. Perhaps that's what was confusing you?

Comment: i feel like kicking myself!! thnx jon!!

Answer (score 1):

Well let's check the source code shall we?

Class [Reader](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/Reader.java.html):

```
abstract public int read(char[] cbuf,
    int off,
    int len) throws IOException
```

So, `abstract`, nothing to see here.

Class [InputStreamReader](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.java.html):

```
public int read(char[] cbuf,
    int offset,
    int length) throws IOException 

{
        return sd.read(cbuf, offset, length);
}
```

So here we have an override of the method from `Reader`.

Finally, [FileReader](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/FileReader.java.html) has no such method defined, so it simply inherits it from `InputStreamReader`.